# Solve $\frac{1}{x^{2} - 5x +6} \leq \frac{1}{2}$: should asymptotic limits be included in the set of values for $x$?

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, limits, inequality

I am looking at an (advanced level) school text book question "find the set of values of $x$ for which $\frac{1}{z^{2} - 5x + 6} \leq \frac{1}{2}.$"

Algebraic / graphical approaches yield two sets of solutions. One set is $x \leq 1$ and $x \geq 4$. The other set, according to my computations, should be $2 < x < 3$, and I exclude the ends of the interval since the function $f(x) = \frac{1}{x^{2} - 5x + 6}$ has asymptotes at $2$ and $3$. But the book says the solution is $2 \leq x \leq 3$.

Technically we can write one-sided limits $\lim_{x \to 2^{-}} f(x) = \lim_{x \to 3^{-}} = -\infty $, which would be less than $\frac{1}{2}$ and inequality is satisfied. But considering the limit on the other side, we have  $\lim_{x \to 2^{+}} f(x) = \lim_{x \to 3^{+}} = +\infty $, and of course the inequality doesn't hold...

So what would be the completely "correct" way to write this solution set? Is it $2 < x < 3$ or $2 \leq x \leq 3$ ?

Comment: For me, such an inequation is defined if and only if all terms are defined, so this set should be $(2,3)$.

Answer (score 3):

The expression is undefined for $x=2$ and $x=3$, so $2\leq x\leq3$ cannot be correct. You are right in saying that it should be $2<x<3$ (and $x\leq1$ and $x\geq4$).